# Question about loop control issue

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to programming and try to calculate the values of `A[t]` for $t$ from 0 to 0.5 in steps of 0.025 as follows but it does not work;

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit=Infinity},
  Mass = m = 500000;
  StiffnessCoefficient = k =300000000;
  {NaturalFrequency = Sqrt[k/m], Period = 2*Pi/NaturalFrequency, FundamentalFrequency = 2*Pi}//N;
  P0 = 5000000;
  P[t_] := P0*Sin[FundamentalFrequency*t];
  Δτ = 0.025;
  A[0] = 0;
  A[t_] := A[t - Δτ] + P[t - Δτ]*Cos[FundamentalFrequency*(t - Δτ)] + P[t]*Cos[FundamentalFrequency*t];
  Table[A[t], {t, 0.025, 0.5, 0.025}]
]
```

I also tried different looping structures using `Do`, `For` or `While` sequences but I don't understand how to achieve it.

Could you help me solve my problem please ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you are indexing into `A` with real (floating point) numbers. Since these are never exact, there are values that cannot be computed. To fix, remove the `Block[ ]` and change:

```
Δτ = 25/1000;
Table[A[t], {t, 25/1000, 1/2, 25/1000}] // N
```

This indexes with exact numbers and so gives an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @bill s that is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Probably a more economical change (and possibly faster) is to change the definition of `A[0]` to `A[0.]`

Comment: @Carlo -- I don't think that works. The problem is that real/floating point numbers experience round off errors and once an error (no matter how tiny) occurs, you'll end up with undefined terms.

Comment: You might be right, I only checked without the Block and the first two iterations were working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this produces what you seek

```
P[t_] := 5000000 Sin[2. Pi t];
Δτ = 0.025;
Accumulate[
 Table[
  P[t - Δτ] Cos[2. Pi (t - Δτ)] + P[t] Cos[2. Pi t], 
  {t, Δτ, 0.5, Δτ}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but why isn't P evaluated in your piece of code @Henrick Schumacher ?

Comment: I do not understand your question; `P` _is_ evaluated. Maybe you are missing `A`? That's what `Accumulate` is good for.

Comment: Sorry for that, I said that because I obtain {1. p[0.]+0.987688 p[0.025],1. p[0.]+1.97538  etc... instead of a list of the values I seek.

Comment: With my code? Impossible. There is no lower case `p`.

Comment: its the same thing with the capital P. I tried another time but it does not change anything, I don't understand why.

Comment: Please, restart the kernel (with `Exit` and Shift+Enter) and _copy_ the code here into your notebook.